# batch file name from loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I get files from ftp.
I need each file to be copied to a new folder that will be the right() 9 positions of the filename.

```
example filename: name_file_decw32014
required foldername: decw32014
```

when I run it and put the file name in a variable I don't see the name

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
open ftp.il.xxxx.com
oren
Dev123$

CD  D:\oren\ftp
binary
prompt n
mget *.xxx

for /R D:\oren\ftp %%i IN (*.xxx*) DO (
 set filename=%%~ni
 set filenameRight=!filename:~0,-9!

 PAUSE
 if not exist "D:\oren\ftp\!filenameRight!" mkdir D:\oren\ftp\!filenameRight!

 copy %%i D:\oren\ftp\!filenameRight!
 pause
 close
 bye
)
```

filenameRight does not change into decw32014 at runtime!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 set filenameRight=!filename:~0,-9!
```

should be

```
 set filenameRight=!filename:~-9!
```

The substring syntax is

```
%var:~start,length% if start >=0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start >=0 and endpos <0
%var:~start,length% if start <0 and length >0
%var:~start,endpos% if start <0 and endpos <0
```

- length/endpos may be omitted. If omitted, the substring is "from the start position to the end"
- `%` may be `!` for `delayedexpansion` mode

So - your code should have returned "name_file_" as `filenameright` (you did not say what it returned)

?? Are you sure `close` `bye` should be within the loop? I'd suggest they should be outside (before the `for`) - but I rarely use those facilities.